# How do I change list order in a dialog box on Android

Tags: android, android-cursor

I have a dialog listing my results from a sqlite database but it list them backward (oldest entries first). How can I resort this list(newest listed first)? Please help. Thanks!

```
    if (view == btnViewAll) {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM number", null);
        if (c.getCount() == 0) {
            showMessage("Error", "No records found");
            return;
        }
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            buffer.append("Meter Number: " + c.getString(0) + "\n");
            buffer.append("Read: " + c.getString(1) + c.getString(2) +c.getString(3) + c.getString(4) + c.getString(5) + "\n");
            buffer.append("Date Read: " + c.getString(6) + "\n\n");
        }
        showMessage("Meter Details", buffer.toString());
    }


}

public void showMessage(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change you query and you are done

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM number ORDER BY <column_name> DESC", null);
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't always pull up the last input. Could I add a column that would give each input a row number that would auto increase? If so I have no idea where to start on how to code that. Can you help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I replaced it with this:

```
    if (view == btnViewAll) {
        if (editText6.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM number ORDER BY id DESC", null);
            if (c.getCount() == 0) {
                Toast ToastMessage = Toast.makeText(this, "      No Records Found      ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                ToastMessage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                View toastView = ToastMessage.getView();
                toastView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape9);
                ToastMessage.show();
                return;
            }
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
               // buffer.append("Entry Id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Meter Number: " + c.getString(1) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Read: " + c.getString(2) + c.getString(3) + c.getString(4) + c.getString(5) + c.getString(6) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Status: " + c.getString(8) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Address: " + c.getString(9) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Date Read: " + c.getString(7) + "\n\n");
            }
            showMessage("Meter Details", buffer.toString());
        } else {
            if (editText6.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM number WHERE meter='" + editText6.getText() + "'ORDER BY id DESC", null);
                if (c.getCount() == 0) {
                    Toast ToastMessage = Toast.makeText(this, "      No Records Found      ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    ToastMessage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                    View toastView = ToastMessage.getView();
                    toastView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape9);
                    ToastMessage.show();
                    return;
                }
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    //buffer.append("Entry Id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Meter Number: " + c.getString(1) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Read: " + c.getString(2) + c.getString(3) + c.getString(4) + c.getString(5) + c.getString(6) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Status: " + c.getString(8) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Address: " + c.getString(9) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Date Read: " + c.getString(7) + "\n\n");
                }
                showMessage("Meter Details", buffer.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
public void showMessage(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}
```